# Select out a plane in C++ OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a Mat in OpenCV that is

```
32FC1 : dims=3 sizes size[0]=3 size[1]=15 size[2]=15
```

It represents a region of a camera input in RGB converted to range 0.0 to 1.0 float per color
and is called fovea.

I want to select out a single plane to a matrix, like...
Mat green = fovea.selectPlane(1)

I tried

```
Mat rgb[3]
split(fovea, rgb);
```

But I then get

```
32FC1 : dims=3 sizes size[0]=3 size[1]=15 size[2]=15
8UC1 : dims=0 rows=0 cols=0
8UC1 : dims=0 rows=0 cols=0
```

and what I want is 3 Mat's like

```
32FC1 : cols=15 rows=15
32FC1 : cols=15 rows=15
32FC1 : cols=15 rows=15
```

How is this done?

----------- Note, my CV Matrix debug functions are -----------------

```
string OpenCVHelpers::CVTypeToStr(const int type) {
    string r;

    uchar depth = type & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK;
    uchar chans = 1 + (type >> CV_CN_SHIFT);

    switch (depth) {
    case CV_8U:  r = "8U"; break;
    case CV_8S:  r = "8S"; break;
    case CV_16U: r = "16U"; break;
    case CV_16S: r = "16S"; break;
    case CV_32S: r = "32S"; break;
    case CV_32F: r = "32F"; break;
    case CV_64F: r = "64F"; break;
    default:     r = "User"; break;
    }

    r += "C";
    r += (chans + '0');

    return r;
}

std::string OpenCVHelpers::CVMatrixInfo(const cv::Mat& m) {
    string r = CVTypeToStr(m.type());
    r += " : dims=";
    r += to_string(m.dims);
    if (m.dims >= 3) {
        r += " sizes ";
        for (int i = 0; i < m.dims; i++) {
            r += "size[" + to_string(i) + "]=" + to_string(m.size[i]) + " ";
        }
    }
    else {
        r += " rows=" + to_string(m.rows) + " cols=" + to_string(m.cols);
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: Maybe [cv::extractChannel](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gacc6158574aa1f0281878c955bcf35642) is what you need.

Comment: the issue here is that it's a weird Mat that isn't 2-dimensional with 3-channel elements, but actually 3-dimensional, AND the color channel appears to be on the outside. how did you make that Mat?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I think it's a common layout in Matlab (i.e. planar instead of interleaved , the color channel is the outer dimesion).

Comment: this isn't a matlab question. you should not think that I'm unfamiliar with that dimension order. please review my comment. -- that remains an "unusual" cv::Mat. there is little to no support (in terms of methods on the type and library functions to handle them) for n-dimensional cv::Mat.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have actually read your comment, and was merely speculating about the source of the `cv::Mat` unusual structure (I had these kind of issues e.g. when implemeting Matlab MEX logic using opencv).

Comment: If you have a `cv::Mat` with planar representation (i.e. the outer dim is the channel), you might be able to do what you need: you could access the data pointer, and then (assuming no padding) - the 1st 225 (15x15) `float`s are the 1st plane, the 2nd 225 `floats` are the 2nd plane etc. You could construct 3 `cv::Mat`s from the data pointer above with a little pointer arithmetics (without copy). If you have padding you can use the `cv::Mat::step` member to take it into accout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having a `cv::Mat` with **planar representation**.
This means the channel is the outer dimension in the data layout: first comes all the data for the 1st channel/plane, then for the 2nd etc.

In this case you can construct 3 `cv::Mat`s (1 for each channel/plane), by accessing the data pointer of your original `cv::Mat` (without copy), and setting the proper metadata.
Since they share the data, your original `cv::Mat` must outlive the new ones (otherwise you should `clone()` them).

**This is demonstrated below:**

```
int sz[] = { 3, 15, 15 };
cv::Mat m(3, sz, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(333));
std::cout << CVMatrixInfo(m) << "\n";

size_t channelDataSize = m.step[0]; // The size of each plane (will be 15 x 15 x sizeof(float) if there's no padding)
size_t channelStride = m.step[1];   // The stride of the plane image (will be 15 x sizeof(float) if there's no padding)
cv::Mat c0(15, 15, CV_32FC1, m.data + 0 * channelDataSize, channelStride);
cv::Mat c1(15, 15, CV_32FC1, m.data + 1 * channelDataSize, channelStride);
cv::Mat c2(15, 15, CV_32FC1, m.data + 2 * channelDataSize, channelStride);

std::cout << CVMatrixInfo(c0) << "\n";
std::cout << CVMatrixInfo(c1) << "\n";
std::cout << CVMatrixInfo(c2) << "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
32FC1 : dims=3 sizes size[0]=3 size[1]=15 size[2]=15
32FC1 : dims=2 rows=15 cols=15
32FC1 : dims=2 rows=15 cols=15
32FC1 : dims=2 rows=15 cols=15
```

**Note** that you might still have an issue of the images being transposed (depends if your data is row-major or column-major).